# (analysis)Let sequence $(F_n)_{n>=0}$ be the Fibonacci numbers satisfying $F_0=F_1=1$

Tags: analysis

Let sequence $(F_n)_{n>=0}$ be the Fibonacci numbers satisfying $F_0=F_1=1$
  and let
\begin{align}
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=a_n
\end{align}
then, prove that a sequence $ (a_{2n-1})_{n>=1}$ is  bounded and  decreasing, and a sequence $ (a_{2n})_{n>=1}$ is bounded and increasing.

I tried to show this using \begin{align}
\frac{2a_{n}+1}{a_n+1}=a_{n+2}
\end{align}
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I can understand why it is bounded ,but by doing the induction, I'm confused with dividing the even and odd

Comment: See the edit of my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the function $f\colon x\in [0,\infty)\mapsto\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$ is bounded and increasing (specifically always between 0 and 2)? This gives you that the sequences are bounded.

Then, check that $a_3<a_1$ (and $a_2>a_0$): what happens when you apply $f$ to both sides? By induction, can you use that to get what you want?

> By induction, you want to show that $a_{2n-1} > a_{2n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$. The base case is covered by $a_1 > a_3$ (this is $n=1$). Assume the induction hypothesis up to $n-1$: $a_{2n-3} > a_{2n-1}$. Since $f$ is (strictly) increasing, applying it to both sides preserves the (strict) inequality: $f(a_{2n-3}) > f(a_{2n-1})$. But $f(a_{2n-3})=a_{2n-3+2} = a_{2n-1}$, and $f(a_{2n-1})=a_{2n+1}$, which shows the induction hypothesis still holds for $n$. (The same argument will work for the even subsequence, with the reverse inequality.)